# Cannot find entry file index.js in any of the roots: [...] (React Native)

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, gradle, expo

I'm trying to build an apk for my first React Native app, but I keep getting an error from gradle saying that it can't find `index.js`. However, I can use the app just find with expo.

Even when I create a new app (with the official template) and then try to build, I get the error:

```
create-react-native-app foo
cd foo
react-native eject
cd android
./gradlew assembleRelease
```

*Note that you must add a name and displayName attribute to **app.json** after you create the app*

Doing these commands still yields this error for me. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Using `create-react-native-app` creates a project that is bootstrapped with Expo.
Whereas `react-native init` creates a project that is just react-native and you have to use xcode and android studio to run your project. That means `create-react-native-app` doesn't allow you to import native modules written in Java and Objetive-C. So you have to use just Expo if you are using `create-react-native-app` because it is not depended on native modules and you can build your Android and iOS app on both operating systems(windows & mac).

Comment: so i have setup project with expo (`react-native-app`), how i can build APK ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***I suggest another method to create new React-native app :***
Steps:

```
 1. intall react-native.
 2. react-native init <project_name>.
 3. cd <project_name>.
 4. `react-native start`.(do not close it).
 5. (Open another window in terminal run this command) `react-native run-android`.
```

I hope this method help you.